# Add user settings to specific roles

Tags: php, user-roles, conditional-content

Is it possible to do this? I already know about get current_user_can(), which does not work like I need. I'd like to be able to use an array if there are multiple roles.

```
// Check roles to only add fields to necessary users
function check_role( $user ) {
    $user_role = get_user_role($user->ID);

    if($user_role == 'author') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'check_role');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'check_role');

if(check_role()) {
    add_action('show_user_profile', 'add_user_fields');
    add_action('edit_user_profile', 'add_user_fields');
    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_fields' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the profile page exists a global variable `$profileuser`. The member `$profileuser->roles` is an array of all roles for that user.

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
// Plugin Name: personal_options

add_action( 'personal_options', 'print_user_roles');

function print_user_roles()
{
    global $profileuser;

    print '<pre>$profileuser->roles = '
        . htmlspecialchars(
            var_export( $profileuser->roles, TRUE ), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE
        )
        . '</pre>';
}
```

Output:

```
$profileuser->roles = array (
  0 => 'administrator',
  1 => 'editor',
)
```

Use this list to compare the roles.

Comment: You are amazing good sir! Works like a charm, thanks.